# cant create new database after trying to change id to UUID

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, uuid

I think I really messed something up... I tried to change my flask-sqlalchemy id table with UUID, I  think it cant convert to integer since there is `-` in the UUID, after that I reverted all changes and got back to using `id`, by deleting old database, and just create a new one. but I'm still getting the same error as before

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    is_boss = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    cv3 = db.relationship('CVBase3', backref='author', lazy=True)
    cv4 = db.relationship('CVBase4', backref='author', lazy=True)
    cv5 = db.relationship('CVBase5', backref='author', lazy=True)
    cv6 = db.relationship('CVBase6', backref='author', lazy=True)
    cv7 = db.relationship('CVBase7', backref='author', lazy=True)
    cv8= db.relationship('CVBase8', backref='author', lazy=True)
    cv9 = db.relationship('CVBase9', backref='author', lazy=True)
    worker = db.relationship('WorkerRegister', backref='author', lazy=True)
    employer = db.relationship('Employer_Register', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.email}', '{self.image_file}','{self.is_boss}', '{self.date_created}')"
```

and the error that I'm getting
`File "c:\code2\flaskblog\models.py", line 13, in load_user return User.query.get(int(user_id)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12be2f9b-f453-43eb-b10e-9797cb3c657f'`

Comment: I'm not sure if you reverted the right database or reverted it right. ;) The error message is clear. user_id *is* obviously a uuid and the error is then of course that int() cannot convert this uuid string to an integer. Potentially you can have some python application code cached, so the models are not reloaded. You can try to restart the app, maybe deleting *.pyc files (pycache folder) after reverting the db. FWIW: A good terminus to know is "database migration", e.g. via flask-migrate. The idea is to change the schemas and accordingly the data, instead of deleting and creating the db.

Comment: the most interesting thing is that when I removed int() from `return User.query.get(int(user_id))` and it look like this now `return User.query.get(user_id)`, it works fine. And when I opened database with db browser its doesnt show any UUID know its simple `id`

Comment: I can imagine either caching problems (python or browser caches) or the app loads a different database than you have selected in your browser. You can check this by e.g. using flask shell to look into db (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/cli/#open-a-shell) by importing db and calling queries on it. You can also check the flask config (db connection string or file location if sqlite is used).